# adding a new column as sum with map in Pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

i have a pyspark dataframe as below:

```
Stock | open_price | list_price
A     | 100        | 1
B     | 200        | 2
C     | 300        | 3
```

I am trying to achieve the below with map and rdd where it prints out each and indivial row with the stock, open_price*list_price, sum of entire open_price column

```
(A, 100 , 600)
(B, 400, 600)
(C, 900, 600)
```

So using the table above for example the first row: A, 100*1, 100+200+300

I was able to get the first 2 columns using my code below.

```
stockNames = sqlDF.rdd.map(lambda p: (p.stock,p.open_price*p.open_price) ).collect()
for name in stockNames:
    print(name)
```

However, when I try to do sum(p.open_price) as below:

```
stockNames = sqlDF.rdd.map(lambda p: (p.stock,p.open_price*p.open_price,sum(p.open_price)) ).collect()
for name in stockNames:
    print(name)
```

It gave me the error below

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 75.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 75.0 (TID 518, localhost, executor driver): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Spark\spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\worker.py", line 229, in main
  File "C:\Spark\spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\worker.py", line 224, in process
  File "C:\Spark\spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\serializers.py", line 372, in dump_stream
    vs = list(itertools.islice(iterator, batch))
  File "<ipython-input-48-f08584cc31c6>", line 19, in <lambda>
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

How do I add in the sum of open_price inside my map RDD?

Thank you in advance as I am still quite new to RDD and map.

Comment: What error did that give you? And what are you trying to sum?

Comment: I am trying to sum the column open_price 300+200+100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compute sum separately:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [("A", 100, 1), ("B", 200, 2), ("C", 300, 3)],
    ("stock", "price", "list_price")
)

total = df.selectExpr("sum(price) AS total")
```

and either add as a column:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit

df.withColumn("total", lit(total.first()[0])).show()

# +-----+-----+----------+-----+
# |stock|price|list_price|total|
# +-----+-----+----------+-----+
# |    A|  100|         1|  600|
# |    B|  200|         2|  600|
# |    C|  300|         3|  600|
# +-----+-----+----------+-----+
```

or `crossJoin`:

```
df.crossJoin(total).show()

# +-----+-----+----------+-----+
# |stock|price|list_price|total|
# +-----+-----+----------+-----+
# |    A|  100|         1|  600|
# |    B|  200|         2|  600|
# |    C|  300|         3|  600|
# +-----+-----+----------+-----+
```

`RDD.map` is not really applicable here (you could use it in place of `withColumn`, but it is inefficient and I wouldn't recommend that).